# Linq return nothing if nullable data is compared

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have a column in database with value as NULL. and i am reading this value in linq to get the result but linq does not return any result.
my linq looks like

```
dim result= (from t in <tableName> where i.id=Pid)
```

Pid is passed as Nothing and my DB consist this id value as NULL so this linq should return some result but it does not return. Why ?

Comment: null = null doesn't return true, you can probably do something like dim result= (from t in <tableName> where if(i.id.isnull,0,i.id)= if(Pid is nothing, 0 , Pid))  or whatever test for null is again

Answer (score 0):

As best of my knowledge, it is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as `=, <, or <>` in SQL. We will have to use the `IS NULL and IS NOT NULL` operators instead.

You can do what you want in an `if statement` in the host language as follow:

```
if(pid!=null)
{
     dim result= (from t in <tableName> where i.id=Pid)
}
else
{
     dim result= (from t in <tableName> where i.id IS NULL)
}
```

Comment: But it is not always that 'Pid' will have value as NULL...It can have 123 then the result will come perfectly. What needs to be checked when Pid is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

This query is translated into SQL with the following where clause:

```
WHERE [t1].[Id] = @p1
```

The problem here is that null comparison semantics in SQL returns null, which is not true, and the row is filtered.

---

You want, instead, to have this where clause:

```
WHERE [t1].[Id] is null
```

Which you can get with a different query.

```
dim result= (from t in <tableName> where i.id Is Nothing)
```